# How to set a range of int value in C++

Tags: c++

If I have an `int a;` and I want to set a value for this int (`cin >> a;`) in a range `1 < a < 1000`, what is the most effective way how to type it via code? Is there a better way then `if(a <=1 || a >= 1000)`? Since if I would have multiple of `int` which I wanted to be limited by their value, I don't want to type a condition for every single one.

Comment: *I don't want to type a condition for every single one* → Store them in an array and use a loop. That's what computers are designed to do.

Comment: If you need to repeat some code, then create a new function with this code, and call it as many times as you like

Comment: I though about this, but the question is, if its't the most effective way how to do it

Comment: What is your main objective? What you'll do using those numbers? Is it okay to use array? Can you please add an example of with description?

Comment: What does "most effective way" mean? It seems that you're asking for opinions. Unfortunately, opinion-based questions are not appropriate for stackoverflow, but only question that are based on citable facts, and sources.

Comment: "Most effective way" means the fastest and the most used. Sorry, I though that it was obvious

Answer (score 2):

Checking the condition `a <=1 || a >= 1000` is exactly what you'd do 
You will want to use a loop here, though, to re-ask for input if the input is not in the correct range.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `if` is the best way to do what you are asking for. But, if you need to handle multiple `int`s, you should wrap the `if` inside of its own function that you can call whenever needed, eg:

```cpp
int askForInt(int minValue, int maxValue)
{
    int value;
    do {
        cout << "Enter an integer (" << minValue << "-" << maxValue << "): ";
        if (cin >> value) {
            if (value >= minValue && value <= maxValue) break;
            cout << "Value out of range! Try again." << endl;
        }
        else {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "Bad input! Try again." << endl;
       }
    }
    while (true);
    return value;
}

...

a = askForInt(1, 1000);
```